# Copy only the inner elements in a WSO2 SOAP envelope and add a new namespace

Tags: java, xml, xslt, wso2-esb

can you help?

I am trying to extract the core elements from a WSO2 SOAP envelope and forward it to another SOAP service.

Any help is appreciated, thanks for reading

the BEFORE shows the input message I receive,
the AFTER shows the progress I've made so far,
the DESIRED is the output I want and the FINAL OUTPUT will enclose the DESIRED in an element called **request**, the request element is static so it does not need to be in the XSLT transformation and can be excluded from the XSLT transform if it simplifies the solution.

BEFORE:

```
<por:ReadMostRecentPrices xmlns:por="http://PAS_1_1.ESB.OOO.com">
         <header>
            <sourceSystem>EDQC</sourceSystem>
            <userName>someguy</userName>
            <createdUtc>2020-10-10</createdUtc>
            <notes>dev test</notes>
            <serviceKey>password-not</serviceKey>
            <serverEnvironmentType>development</serverEnvironmentType>
         </header>
         <mostRecentPricesSet>
            <securityDurableKeys>
               <securityDurableKey>LZ0080300001</securityDurableKey>
               <securityDurableKey>LZ0080300002</securityDurableKey>
            </securityDurableKeys>
            <priceScheme>01</priceScheme>
            <date>2020-10-10</date>
         </mostRecentPricesSet>
      </por:ReadMostRecentPrices>
```

AFTER:

```
    <por:ReadMostRecentPrices xmlns:por="http://PAS_1_1.ESB.OOO.com">
             <mostRecentPricesSet>
                <urn:securityDurableKeys xmlns:urn="urn:epaservice">
                   <securityDurableKey>LZ0080300001</securityDurableKey>
                   <securityDurableKey>LZ0080300002</securityDurableKey>
                </urn:securityDurableKeys>
                <urn:priceScheme xmlns:urn="urn:epaservice">01</urn:priceScheme>
                <urn:date xmlns:urn="urn:epaservice">2020-10-10</urn:date>
             </mostRecentPricesSet>
          </por:ReadMostRecentPrices>
```

DESIRED:

```
    <urn:securityDurableKeys xmlns:urn="urn:epaservice">
      <urn:securityDurableKey>LZ0080300001</urn:securityDurableKey>
      <urn:securityDurableKey>LZ0080300002</urn:securityDurableKey>
    </urn:securityDurableKeys>
    <urn:priceScheme xmlns:urn="urn:epaservice">01</urn:priceScheme>
    <urn:date xmlns:urn="urn:epaservice">2020-10-10</urn:date>
```

FINAL OUTPUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urn:request xmlns:urn="urn:epaservice">
  <urn:securityDurableKeys>
    <urn:securityDurableKey>LZ0080300001</urn:securityDurableKey>
    <urn:securityDurableKey>LZ0080300002</urn:securityDurableKey>
  </urn:securityDurableKeys>
  <urn:priceScheme>01</urn:priceScheme>
  <urn:date>2020-10-10</urn:date>
</urn:request>
```

this my XSLT:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:urn="urn:epaservice" xmlns:PortfolioAccountingService_1_1="http://PAS_1_1.ESB.OOO.com">
           <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes">
           </xsl:output>
           <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
             <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
               </xsl:apply-templates>
             </xsl:copy>
           </xsl:template>
           <!-- Removes the header START -->
           <xsl:template match="header">
           </xsl:template>
           <!-- Removes the header END -->
           <!-- mostRecentPrices operation START -->
           <xsl:template match="PortfolioAccountingService_1_1:ReadMostRecentPrices/mostRecentPricesSet/*">
             <xsl:element name="urn:{local-name()}" namespace="urn:epaservice">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
             </xsl:element>
           </xsl:template>
           <xsl:template match="PortfolioAccountingService_1_1:ReadMostRecentPrices/mostRecentPricesSet/securityDurableKeys/*">
             <xsl:element name="urn:{local-name()}" namespace="urn:epaservice">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
             </xsl:element>
           </xsl:template>
           <!-- mostRecentPrices operation END -->
         </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Constraints or gotchas:

- I am using Windows PowerShell and System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform to test my transform which works perfectly if I use <xsl:template match="/"> in the first template match
- The production system uses org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator, and when I use the directive <xsl:template match="/"> the Apache XSLT processor fails with the error in bold below

- It seems like I have to use <xsl:template match="@* | node()">

**TID: [0] [ESB] [2020-10-09 09:02:24,722] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator} -  Unable to perform XSLT transformation using : Value {name ='null', keyValue ='PortfolioAccountingService_1_1_EPAOutbound_XSLT'} against source XPath : s11:Body/child::*[position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[position()=1] reason : javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[8,14]
Message: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. {org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[8,14]
Message: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you could do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:urn="urn:epaservice" 
    xmlns:por="http://PAS_1_1.ESB.OOO.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="por">
     
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="por:ReadMostRecentPrices/mostRecentPricesSet"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="mostRecentPricesSet">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="securityDurableKeys"/>
    <urn:priceScheme xmlns:urn="urn:epaservice"><xsl:value-of select="priceScheme"/></urn:priceScheme>
    <urn:date xmlns:urn="urn:epaservice"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></urn:date>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="securityDurableKeys">
    <urn:securityDurableKeys xmlns:urn="urn:epaservice">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="securityDurableKey"/>
    </urn:securityDurableKeys>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="securityDurableKey">
    <urn:securityDurableKey><xsl:value-of select="."/></urn:securityDurableKey>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEcZxB

It's much simpler if you can test your transformation on the same engine than the one you will be using on your server.

Comment: Sebastien, thank you very much, 1 the XSLT you provided works, 2 you've given me a greater understanding in what xsl:apply-templates does and 3 I didn't even know that the site xsltfiddle existed.

Comment: I think the problem is mainly to do with the different XSLT processors as the Apache processor is reporting an error that I think with how the XSLT is applied, it doesn't work within WSO2 but it works using my test tool that utilises Windows PowerShell and the System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform type

Comment: From the error you posted in your original question, it seems like the XML being passed to the transformation is not well-formed. It would be good if you find out which XSLT engine it is using and try to run your transformation using that same engine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr